# Printing elements from Nth index onward in an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm trying to find a way to take an array of five integers and print the last three. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java-8, you can do this :

```
Arrays.stream(array).skip(2).forEach(System.out::println);
```

There won't be any exceptions thrown even if you pass a value to `skip` that is greater than the length of the array. You will simply get no output in such a case.

If you are not using Java-8, I don't see any challenge. Just loop through index 3 to n and print the elements.

Answer (score 0):

check the following code snippet

```
  //its three because you want to display last three elements.Note it should be less than array length
    int pointer=3;
    int[] inputArray= {1,2,3,4,5};
    for(int i=inputArray.length-pointer;i<inputArray.length;i++){

        System.out.println(inputArray[i]);
    }
```